# replace unicode character

Tags: c#, regex, string, replace

```
String jData="Memur adayar\u0131n\u0131n en b\u00fcy\u00fck sorunar"
    + "\u0131ndan KPSS \u0 131 ";   
jData = Regex.Replace(jData, @"\\u0 ", @"\\u0", RegexOptions.Compiled).Trim();
```

I have to replace `"\u0 "` in jData with `"\u0"` (i.e. remove the trailing whitespace character if there is one) but the method I used isn't working. What should I do?

Comment: But in your code, they both `u0` ?

Comment: Where does `jData` really come from? Your current code won't compile because `\u0 ` isn't valid in a C# string literal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you've got some malformed Unicode escapes in the string and you want to fix them by removing any whitespace after the `0`.  That's simple enough:

```
jData = Regex.Replace(jData, @"(\\u0)\s+(\w+)", "$1$2");
```

The hardest part of all this is figuring out what all the backslashes are supposed to mean.  C# can helps you with that supports an alternative string literal syntax for  verbatim string, the only character that you have to escape with a backslash is the backslash itself.  (You have to escape quotation marks too, but you do that with another quote, i.e. `""`).

---

With that out of the way, the real reason I answered this question was to advise you not to use `RegexOptions.Compiled`.  I'm sure you've heard many people say it makes the regex work faster.  That's true, but it's an oversimplification.  Read [this article](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/03/to-compile-or-not-to-compile.html) for a good discussion of this issue.  Do yourself a favor and forget `RegexOptions.Compiled` even exists until you run into a problem you can't solve without it.

Answer (score 0):

find:    `@"\\u0 "`
replace: `@"\\u0"`

they are the same. Try it with an capital O or normal o

Comment: No they aren't.There are space character in @"\\u0 ".

Comment: Also, your replacement string should be either `"@\u0"` or `"\\u0"`.  The way you've got it now, you're replacing the one backslash in the original with two backslashes.

Answer (score 0):

I think I got it working

```
string jData= @"Memur adayar\u0131n\u0131n en b\u00fcy\u00fck sorunar\u0131ndan KPSS \u0 131 ";   
jData = Regex.Replace(jData, @"\\u0 ", @"\u0", RegexOptions.Compiled).Trim();
```

Notice I added an extra `'@'` in front of the input string. And in the regex part I changed the third argument to `@"\u0"`

Answer (score 0):

There's a problem with your example string.  I'm supposing that you actually wanted the backslashes in the string, in which case the simplest approach is to put @ before the string literals. And then I believe you have the opposite problem in the second line, where you should have either used just one backslash in each string, or omitted the @.
There's no reason to use Regex.Replace() here.  jData.Replace() would suffice just fine:

```
        String jData=@"Memur adayar\u0131n\u0131n en b\u00fcy\u00fck sorunar"
            + @"\u0131ndan KPSS \u0 131 ";   
        jData = jData.Replace(@"\u0 ", @"\u0").Trim();
```